# Boost directory_iterator: 'begin' and 'end' not declared

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to learn how to use the Boost C++ library, but I've run into a problem.  When running the following boost::filesystem tutorial code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using std::cout;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        cout << "Usage: tut3 path\n";
        return 1;
    }

    path p (argv[1]);

    try
    {
        if (exists(p))
        {
            if (is_regular_file(p))
                cout << p << " size is " << file_size(p) << '\n';

            else if (is_directory(p))
            {
                cout << p << " is a directory containing:\n";

                for (directory_entry& x : directory_iterator(p))
                    cout << "    " << x.path() << '\n'; 
            }
            else
                cout << p << " exists, but is not a regular file or directory\n";
        }
        else
            cout << p << " does not exist\n";
    }

    catch (const filesystem_error& ex)
    {
        cout << ex.what() << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and compiling with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main -L$BOOST_ROOT -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
```

or:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main -L$BOOST_ROOT -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```

where BOOST_ROOT is the path where I extracted boost_1_62_0.tar.gz, I get the following error:

```
FoamData.cpp:36:76: error: ‘begin’ was not declared in this scope
          for (auto&& x : boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(p))
                                                                 ^
FoamData.cpp:36:76: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:66:0,
                 from FoamData.hpp:4,
                 from FoamData.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/range_access.h:87:5: note:   ‘std::begin’
     begin(_Tp (&__arr)[_Nm])
     ^
FoamData.cpp:36:76: error: ‘end’ was not declared in this scope
          for (auto&& x : boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(p))
                                                                 ^
FoamData.cpp:36:76: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:66:0,
                 from FoamData.hpp:4,
                 from FoamData.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/range_access.h:97:5: note:   ‘std::end’
     end(_Tp (&__arr)[_Nm])
     ^
make: *** [FoamData.o] Error 1
```

I apologize, in advance, if I have glossed over something obvious.

**EDIT**

The following statement from subsequent boost_filesystem tutorials gave the same error:

```
for(auto&& x : directory_iterator(p))
```

Code source:
[boost::filesystem tutorials](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html)

**UPDATE**

I recompiled boost_1_62_0 and ran the tutorial scripts to build the tutorial code (per the boost filesystem tutorial).  The built tutorial programs work properly.  However, when compiling using g++ outside of `$BOOST_ROOT` I am getting the following error:

`./tester: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.62.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Below is my `makefile`:

```
CC=g++
INCLUDE=-I/usr/local/boost_1_62_0
CFLAGS=-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g
LDFLAGS=-lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
LDLIB=-L/usr/local/boost_1_62_0/stage/lib

all: tester

tester: main.o
    $(CC) main.o $(LDLIB) $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o tester

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) -c main.cpp $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm *.o tester
```

**FINAL UPDATE**

I was able to eliminate the last of my errors by adding this to my `.bashrc`:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$BOOST_ROOT/stage/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"`

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Works fine for me with g++ 6.2.0 and boost 1.62 (from msys2) and also on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dab4a22a907c2a65) (g++ 6.1.0 boost 1.61).

Comment: @jv_: I updated from g++-5.4.0 to 6.2.0, but it made no difference on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably your code is using the wrong (and outdated) system Boost libraries where the `begin()` and `end()` members are not provided in `directory_iterator`.

The reason is, that in your g++ command line you have provided an additional library path using `-L`, however you forgot to add an extra include path using `-I`.

You can add a compile time check for the boost version like this:

```
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(BOOST_VERSION >= 106200) // check for at least 1.62.0
```

Comment: I added `-I$BOOST_ROOT` and it now compiles fine.  However, I get a segmentation fault when running the compiled program.  Am I not using the correct include path?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following syntax instead:

```
   if (is_directory(p))
   {
      directory_iterator end_iter;

      for (directory_iterator dir_itr(p);
          dir_itr != end_iter;
          ++dir_itr)
      {
         std::cout << dir_itr->path().filename() << "\n";
      }
   }
```

This will list all the files in the directory.

The problem with your code is that you're not treating the object returned by `directory_iterator(p)` as an iterator.

The syntax you are using for the `for` loop expects a [range expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), which should in this case be an object that has a `begin` and `end` method for getting at iterators. As you can see from the errors, the compiler is looking for these members.

Howerver, you've already created the begin iterator explictly - you're 'too late' to use the range syntax for the `for` loop.

Comment: That worked, and thank you for the solution!  However, I'm still curious, is the tutorial code just faulty or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @user3489620: I've clarified in my answer

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me!  Unfortunately, the code was copied directly from the Boost website, which is why I figured the problem was on my end.

Comment: The Boost code snippets are fine. You were most probably including the wrong headers (see my answer).